# connect google calendar service java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I want to create an application in java using Google Calendar Api , but I try to connect to api service but it's wrong. 
Here is my code (with Eclipse )

```
 GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())

              .setServiceAccountId("*****************")
    //    .setServiceAccountUser("my e-mail adress")
              .setClientSecrets("","********")
        //    .setServiceAccountScopes(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)
              .setJsonFactory(new GsonFactory())

              .build();
            Calendar  client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

the error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.<init>(GoogleCredential.java:323)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.build(GoogleCredential.java:539)
    at google_calendar.add_evenement.main(add_evenement.java:21)
```

Comment: According to your error message there is a problem with the authentication, could you provide the output with changed authentication? 
You can use this: `GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()).setServiceAccountId("*****************").setClientSecrets("","********").setJsonFactory(new GsonFactory()).setAccessType("offline").build();`

Comment: thank you , but i have the same error

Comment: It seems odd to me that you're setting a service account ID and a client secrets - normally you *either* use service account details *or* you use a client ID/secret. Likewise, it's odd that you're setting a service account ID but nothing else in terms of service account secrets.

Comment: if i understand you , I changed setServiceAcco‌​untId to setServiceAccountUser (***** user Id **** ) , but the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so, check [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

As discussed, if you have delegated domain-wide access to the service account and you want to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of the user account with the `setServiceAccountUser` method of the `GoogleCredential` factory. For example:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
    .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
    .build();
```

Then, [calling Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#callinganapi) using Java:

> Use the `GoogleCredential` object to call Google APIs by completing the following steps:
>
> 1. Create a service object for the API that you want to call using the `GoogleCredential` object. For example:

```
SQLAdmin sqladmin =
    new SQLAdmin.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
```

> 2. Make requests to the API service using the [interface provided by the service object](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client). For example, to list the instances of Cloud SQL databases in the exciting-example-123 project:

```
SQLAdmin.Instances.List instances =
    sqladmin.instances().list("exciting-example-123").execute();
```

Comment: thank you for your help , 
i use your explication and the error is :
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized ....

Comment: You may want to check if the access token you're using is either expired or invalid. See suggested actions [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials).